# Entity Framework: Why do the templates no longer generate ".designer.cs" source files

Tags: visual-studio, entity-framework, visual-studio-2012, t4

The default type generation in Entity Framework 3.5/4.0 emits each of the types in "Xxxx.designer.cs" source files (where "Xxxx" is the name of the type being generated). This then allowed for the developer to generate his own "Xxxx.cs" source files where further implementation could take place, or attributes could be added to Metadata classes etc.

The more recent T4 templates that have been made available (POCO, Self Tracking etc.), including the default type generation in VS2012, all genrate "Xxxx.cs" themselves without the ".designer" suffix.

I know that it is easy enough to override the behaviour of the T4 templates to emit the ".designer" within the file names, but am I missing something here where we are actually being discouraged to extend these classes through the partial definitions?

In a recent project where I generated Self Tracking Entities, I found that I had to rename the emitted files so that I could extend the definitions with Metadata class attributes as well as overrides of .Equals(object) and .GetHashcode() (otherwise EF could not detect duplicates properly) for example.

Is there something that I have missed where we are now expected to leave the emitted partial classes as they are or is this merely an oversight and are most of you also having to rename source files being emitted?

Answer (score 0):

Code generation strategy has changed in VS2012. Before the code that was generated was using EntityObject based entities and a context class derived from the ObjectContext class. VS2012 by default generates POCO entities and DbContext dervied context. If you still want ObjectContext based context and EntityObject based entities you need to:

1. Right-click on the designer surface and select properties
2. Change the "Code Generation Strategy" from "None" to "Default"
3. Remove .tt files from your solution to avoid having both contexts and duplicate entities.

Comment: I think you may have misunderstood the question. I am not trying to restore ObjectContext, I am asking why the source file naming strategy has changed to no longer include ".designer".

Comment: Yes, clearly misunderstood the question. These files are no longer generated by the designer (notice the code generation strategy is set to None) by but VS that invokes T4 template processing. T4 processor creates a file that has the same name as the T4 template being processed. You may try renaming T4 files - if you do that you may however need to rename the edmx file (I am not sure about this). This rename was not done to discourage extending generated classes.

Comment: Thanks; it is the last bit of that I was trying to get at. I know I can rename the generated source files by editing the T4 templates (and have done this on numerous occasions) - I just wanted to know if I was now going against the grain.